# How to share an AirTag with family members

Tags: ios, find-my, airtag

I have an AirTag. I would like my wife to be able to see where it is.

We are part of a family in terms of AppleID (if I download an app, she can also install it).

Is there a way she can also access the AirTag’s location?

Answer (score 13):

**Update on 6/5/23:** With iOS 17, likely available this fall, Find My item sharing has been added. Information is not yet available on how this works, but I'm adding this note for anyone curious about it.

---

You cannot share the location of an AirTag with other people.

The only privilege currently granted is indefinite silencing of AirTags owned by family members:

> If the AirTag is attached to an item you're borrowing, you can tap
> Pause Safety Alerts to turn off "AirTag Detected" notifications for
> one day. If you're borrowing an AirTag from a member of your Family
> Sharing group, you can turn off Safety Alerts for one day or
> indefinitely.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212227