# Sharing Apple Airtag with family: Unable to share AirTag

Tags: iphone, ios, sharing, airtag

I am trying to share my AirTag. I followed the Apple Support document [Share an AirTag or other item in Find My on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph419cc5f28/ios) and updated my iOS as indicated in an answer for [How to share an AirTag with family members](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419775/how-to-share-an-airtag-with-family-members). I have the option of adding people, but when I click it, I get to choose a contact. When I chose the person, who has an even newer iPhone than mine, it says, "**unable to share AirTag XXX is not eligible for sharing**". I was never asked to type in an Apple ID as described in the documentation. What might be wrong here?

Comment: Are you unable to share any AirTag?

Comment: @Ezekiel Yes same for any.

Comment: You may need to reach out to Apple support, unless someone else has this error and has fixed it, it seems like Apple might need to identify why your account isn't allowing it.

Comment: @Ezekiel I solved it by removing it from my phone, adding on my wifes phone and sharing from hers to mine. Still never found out why I can't share to her.